# Django Ajax - POST request succeeds, data not saved on DB

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I'm using a bootstrap modal to allow firefighter to update their status in an app I'm working on.  The modal has buttons that make a POST request when clicked.  `csrf tokens are disabled for testing purposes`

models.py

```
class Firefighter(models.Model):  

  STATUS_OPTIONS = (
    ('AV', 'Available'),
    ('OD', 'On Duty'),
    ('UN', 'Unavailable'),
    ('LV', 'Leave'),
  )

  first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length = 200)
  last_name = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length = 200)
  status = models.CharField("Status", max_length = 20 , choices=STATUS_OPTIONS, default='Available')
```

views.py

```
def updateStatus(request, id):
  from django.http import JsonResponse
  if request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax():
    try:
      obj = Firefighter.objects.get(id=id)
      obj.data_attr = request.POST['status']
      obj.save()
      return JsonResponse({'status':'Record Saved'})
    except Firefighter.DoesNotExist:
      return JsonResponse({'status':'Record does not exist'})
  else:
      return JsonResponse({'status':'Invalid POST request'})
```

Returns the `Record Saved` JSON response when run.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^status/$', views.status, name='status'),
    url(r'^status/update/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.updateStatus, name='update'),
```

button jQuery

```
$('#btnAvailable').on('click', function() {
    // You gotta include the csrf_token in your post data
    $.post(`/status/update/${clickedID}/`, {'status': 'AV'}, function() {
      $('#change-status').modal('hide');
      location.reload(true)
    });
  });
```

Everything runs as it should, chrome shows no console errors for the POST request and yet the `status` does not save on the DB.  For example `/status/update/22/` has their status currently set to `UN` (Unavailable) the post request should set their status to `AV` (Available) however the status never changes on the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I'm seeing, you're not setting `status` at all, your changing an attribute called data_attr (attaching it on runtime) and then calling save, which results in nothing saved in the DB, as expected.

Just change your `data_attr` to `status` and you're good to go

```
def updateStatus(request, id):
  from django.http import JsonResponse
  if request.method=='POST' and request.is_ajax():
    try:
      obj = Firefighter.objects.get(id=id)
      obj.status = request.POST['status']
      obj.save()
      return JsonResponse({'status':'Record Saved'})
    except Firefighter.DoesNotExist:
      return JsonResponse({'status':'Record does not exist'})
  else:
      return JsonResponse({'status':'Invalid POST request'})
```

Also you have "Available" as default for your status, while your choices are otherwise (AV, OD, ...).

This should also be fixed, something like

```
STATUS_AVAILABLE = 'AV'
STATUS_ON_DUTY = 'OD'
STATUS_UN_AVAILABLE = 'UV'
STATUS_ON_LEAVE = 'OL'

STATUS_OPTIONS = (
    (STATUS_AVAILABLE, 'Available'),
    (STATUS_ON_DUTY, 'On Duty'),
    (STATUS_UN_AVAILABLE, 'Unavailable'),
    (STATUS_ON_LEAVE, 'Leave'),
  )
status = models.CharField(..., choices=STATUS_OPTIONS, default=STATUS_AVAILABLE)
```

Comment: Can't believe I've been staring at this for two hours and didn't see that.  Fresh eyes right?  Cheers buddy!